# WordPress blog post show more post button

Tags: wordpress

On WordPress how to add a condition on a **show more post button** that will only show when post is more than 10.

I don't know what to do?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Could you please try https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ this plugin ?

Comment: @purvik7373

 I code it this way  I don't know how to add condition on that

' <div class="more_button"> 
<a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>latest">Show More Post</a></div>'

I don't know how to add a condition on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin.Ajax Load More is a powerful solution for infinite scrolling

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/